# Change voice to female voice Twilio Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, twilio, dialogflow-es, twilio-twiml

I am using an official repository https://github.com/twilio/media-streams of Twilio to connect Dialogflow with Twilio. Everything is working fine except that I cannot figure out how to change the voice from male to female. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify code from line 30 in dialogflow-utils.js file

```
const initialStreamRequest = {
  queryInput,
  session: sessionPath,
  queryParams: {
    session: sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId),
  },
  outputAudioConfig: {
    audioEncoding: "OUTPUT_AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16",
    synthesizeSpeechConfig: {
      voice: {
        name: "en-US-Wavenet-C"
      },
    },
  },
};
```